# Im trying to write this in Mathematica. It is a recurrence relation for convolution

Tags: functions, difference-equations, convolution

I have tried many things, the relation is in the following picture, x' is a dummy variable.[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please take a minute to read [the tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). As written, this question is not answerable: it is not clear what task you want to accomplish (or what you mean by "write in Mathematica"). Please take a look at the existing highly-voted questions, and model yours on then: use a _concise_ descriptive title. Clearly explain the task you want to solve, what you have done so far, and what difficulty you encountered. Please edit the question and make the necessary improvements (do not use comments to add critical information).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
f[n_] := 
   f[n] = 
     Function[
       {x}, 
       Evaluate@Integrate[f[n - 1][x - x1] f[1][x1], {x1, 0, x}]
     ]
```

For example after specifying

```
 f[1] = Function[{x}, x]
```

`f[10]` gives

```
 x^19/121645100408832000
```

Of course, if `f[1]` is so complicated that Mathematica cannot do some of the convolutions explicitly, this will produce a mess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time !! It seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [`Convolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve):

```
Clear[f]
f[n_] := f[n] = Function[
    y,
    Evaluate @ Convolve[f[n-1][x] UnitStep[x], f[1][x] UnitStep[x], x, y, Assumptions->y>0]
]
f[1] := Function[x, x]
```

Multiplication by [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep) changes the convolution to be over a finite interval (by default, [`Convolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Convolve) uses an infinite interval).

Then, we reproduce @mmeent's answer:

```
f[10][x]
```

> x^19/121645100408832000

Comment: thank you very much. Very helpful !